# Images not showing up in laravel

Tags: laravel

So I have images working on my dev environment, however when i try to see them on the production server I receive a 404 error, the images are located in storage/app/public folder, I have ran the following command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

The output says it works however it is still a 404 error when navigating to /storage/imagefolder/image on the site

Comment: check storage/app/public folder that your images are uploading to this destination.
If storage/app/public folder is empty then you need to store files using Storage helper in laravel

Answer (score 0):

Technically images are accessible through the public folder, not the storage folder.

In your Code you can access them like:

```
<img src="{{ asset('imagefolder/image') }}" />
```

You can find the correct/final image url with:

```
dd(asset('imagefolder/image'));
```

Answer (score 0):

First delete the old symlink

Then from the command:

```
php artisan storage: link
```

And to display files: ‌

```
<img src="{{ asset('imagefolder/fileName') }}" />
```

or

```
<img src="{{ /storage/imagefolder/fileName }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

File permission error on the existing link to storage from the public folder, deleting the link and re running the command fixed the issue.